# How to query firebase event report with hourly breakup in Bigquery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Below big query helps to extract registration event data datewise. But, How to extract registration event data hourwise.  Pls. Help

```
select 
app_info.id,app_info.version,traffic_source.medium,
traffic_source.source,geo.country,geo.city,  
event_date,event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as category,
 FROM `<Table>`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1
where _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190401'  AND '20190402'  
and event_name='Registration'
and param1.key='category' 
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: What is the format of the event_date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your select change `event_date` to `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), HOUR)`